# Update Wordpress database, change post_content hardcoded URLs

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am not a huge expert in MYSQL nor Regex (I guess I need to use some here), I would appreciate any help.
So my problem is that I would like to change some hardcoded URLs in Wordpress post contents to different ones.

Here is an example of a URL:

http://cdn1.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/16211742/Screenshot_051117_101304_AM.jpg

Now, 'cdn1' can be cdn, cdn1 or cdn2. We might need to run 3 queries, but that is not a problem.

I would like to change all instances of this to:

//domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/16211742/Screenshot_051117_101304_AM.jpg

So basically remove the cdn (cdn, cdn1, cdn2) part, and remove the timestamp URL part before the filename.

The Wordpress database is something like this:

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = 
WHERE

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, take a database Backup for safety.**

Then you can do this with SQL Command like this

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

OR you can do this with the plugin called: [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)

There has a tutorial on the plugin page. check that.

Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to move my Wordpress install, I just need to change a couple of URLs

Comment: I understand that. did you saw that plugin?
with that plugin just replace like this:
http://cd1.domain.com/ with
//domain.com/

Comment: I have managed to get the job done with wp search-replace cl tool. Thanks for the replies!